# Iterative programming - jobs are being executed wihtout launching them

Tags: apache-spark

In an iterative algorithm which i developed, where i am calling a function recusively, an unexpected behaviour of tasks execution is happening.

The function itself contains several transformations on an RDD and an action "isEmpty" to stop the recusive execution.

The problem is that the transformations are being evaluated without calling the action.

as described in the code i am calling the action "IsEmpty" only each five iterations. The process function contains only transformations such as : filter, join, broadcast, DF select, cache, coalesce.

```
 var layer_index=0  
 def iterate(layer:RDD[Long])={
 layer.cache()
 if(layer_index%5==0) if(layer.isEmpty) return null
 val nextlayer=process(layer)
 layer_index=layer_index+1
 iterate(nextlayer)
 }
```

But as you can see in the picture below, actions are being executed before the timeline reaches"isEmpty"

[timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THXhm.png)

why i have thread pool executer jobs? those "tread pool executor" jobs corresponds to iterations 2,3,4 where i am not executing "isempty". i should only have "isempty" job which correspond to iteration 5.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What does your `process` function do?

Comment: The process function contains only transformations such as : filter, join, broadcast, DF select, cache, coalesce. no action that is being executed.in "process" i am only applying several transformations on the layer RDD.